# How to change the properties (title, caption) of images in a wordpress page with functions.php?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a wordpress website which is in both english and french, meaning that for every english page, there's its french counterpart with the same content. Until now, when I wanted to add something to it like a slideshow, I'd do two of them and add them on their respective pages but I have a problem with galleries and solo images as their caption and title are used directly in those cases. I don't want to upload each image twice with different properties so I wanted to add a function in php that switches the language for me.

My idea was to put tags in the images caption to have something like that :

```
[EN] EN description
[FR] FR description
```

And have the function get this string and work it to remove what has to be removed for the current page. My problem is that I don't really know php and even less the WordPress api of which I struggle to understand how it works, what I get when I call a function or even what it's talking about in the functions description.

So my question is this: Is there a way to get all the images of a page and edit their properties ? If yes, how ?

I tried to search for clues on the internet and found this code that I wanted to use as a base but I'm not sure it's working:

```
$PageID = get_the_ID();
$Post = get_post( $PageID ); 
$Content = $Post->post_content;
$Regex = '/src="([^"]*)"/';
preg_match_all( $Regex, $Content, $Matches ); 
foreach( $Matches as $Image ):
    echo '<img src="'.$Image.'" alt="'.$Post->post_title.'" title="'.$Post->post_title.'">';
endforeach;
```

Maybe I'm missing something but when I try to print $Matches or $Image in the console, all I get is "Array" and it gives me a broken image with my page title on its side if I try to run it.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: _“but when I try to print $Matches or $Image in the console, all I get is "Array"”_ - echo and print can not directly output arrays, that’s why you only get the _text_ “Array” (and a warning, about array to string conversion), when you try to use those. Use `var_dump` or `print_r` for debug outputs, those can handle arrays properly.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to change HTML markup for each image (ex. add custom attributes to each `<img>`), maybe this is a good thread: [Change html structure of all img tags in Wordpress @ wordpress.stackexchange.com](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/81522/change-html-structure-of-all-img-tags-in-wordpress)

If you want to change how WP outputs the *caption* for an image, which is inserted based on a shortcode in the editor, then this WP codex page should help: [Plugin API/Filter Reference/img caption shortcode @ codex.wordpress.org](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/img_caption_shortcode)

There is an example in the second link. You should be able to get the image caption in a variable (see `$attr['caption']`) - and then you should filter it (ex. remove the [EN] description). But you need to figure how to access the language of the page in that function.